# Auto suggest not working after initialising a variable in beforeEach block

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

Auto Suggest is not working for any variable declared in beforeEach block. If I use "app" variable in it() block, auto suggest is not showing any of the methods. Auto suggest is working in beforeEach block. On pressing Ctrl + Space it is showing all the available methods. I am using visual studio code as the IDE. Mocha is the testing framework.

```
var express = require('express')

describe("#1", async () => {

    let app 

    beforeEach("SetUp", async () => {       
        app = express();   
        app. // First,  Auto suggest is working on pressing Ctrl + Space
    })

    it("Demo Test #1.1", async () =>{

        app.  //Second, Auto suggest not working on pressing Ctrl + Space
       
   })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit***: If you don't want to go all-in with [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), you can do this using [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html), as long as you don't mind adding `@type` annotations where the un-inferrable variables are declared.

```js
const express = require("express")

describe("#1", async () => {
  /** @type {express.Express} */
  let app

  beforeEach("SetUp", () => { app = express() })

  it("Demo Test #1.1", async () => {
    app // autocomplete is now available here
  })
})
```

---

***Original answer below***

VS Code cannot infer type information about a variable set in a callback.

Consider the following simplified example:

```js
let variable

foo(() => {       
    variable = 1
})

bar(() => {       
    variable = 'str'
})

main(() =>{
    // what type is `variable` here?
})
```

If you're willing to switch to TypeScript, this can be solved by adding an annotation to the declaration:

```
let app: Express
```

### Demo

```js
const nonDeterministicTimeout = () =>
    cb => setTimeout(cb, Math.random() * 100)

for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    const foo = nonDeterministicTimeout()
    const bar = nonDeterministicTimeout()
    const main = nonDeterministicTimeout()

    let variable

    foo(() => {       
        variable = 1
    })

    bar(() => {       
        variable = 'str'
    })

    main(() =>{
        console.log(typeof variable)
        // fluctuates arbitrarily between
        // undefined, string, and number
    })
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to make it work, rather than using typescript.

Comment: You can try with [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html). Answer edited with info.

Comment: Thanks Lionel Rowe. It is working. Really appreciate your help.